# How do I get perl to read the values from my html form as unicode?

Tags: html, perl, forms, unicode, utf-8

I have an html form that sends data to .cgi page.  Here is the html:

```
<HTML>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF">

    <FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="test.cgi">


        <B>Write to me below:</B><P>
        <TEXTAREA NAME="feedback" ROWS=10 COLS=50></TEXTAREA><P>

        <CENTER>
            <INPUT TYPE=submit VALUE="SEND">
            <INPUT TYPE=reset VALUE="CLEAR">
        </CENTER>

    </FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is the perl script for test.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use encoding('utf8');
require Encode;
require CGI;


# The following accepts the data from the form and puts it in %FORM

if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST') {
    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);

    foreach $pair (@pairs) {
        ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

    $FORM{$name} = $value;
    }

# The following generates the html for the page

    print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    print "<HTML>\n";
    print "<HEAD>\n";
    print "<TITLE>Thank You!</TITLE>\n";
    print "</HEAD>\n";
    print "<BODY BGCOLOR=#FFFFCC TEXT=#000000>\n";  
    print "<H1>Thank You!</H1>\n";
    print "<P>\n";
    print "<H3>Your feedback is greatly appreciated.</h3><BR>\n";
    print "<P>\n<P>\n";
    print "The user wrote:\n\n";
    print "<P>\n";

# This is print statement A
    print "$FORM{'feedback'}<br>\n";

    $FORM{'feedback'}=~s/(\w)/ $1/g;

# This is print statement B
    print "$FORM{'feedback'}\n";

    print "</BODY>\n";
    print "</HTML>\n";
    exit(0);
}
```

This all works the way it's supposed to if the user enters English text.  However, this will eventually be used in a product where the user will enter Chinese text.  So here's an example of the problem.  If the user enters "中文" into the form, then Print Statement A prints "中文." However, Print Statement B (which prints $value after the regex has been run) prints "&# 2 0 0 1 3;&# 2 5 9 9 1; ".  What I want it to print however is "中 文".  If you want to see this, go to http://thedeandp.com/chinese/input.html and try it yourself.

So basically, what I've figured out is that when perl reads in the form, it's just treating each byte as a character, so the regex adds a space between each byte. Chinese characters use unicode, so it's multiple bytes to a character.  That means the regex breaks up the unicode with a space between the bytes, and that is what produces the output seen in Print Statement B.  I've tried methods like $value = Encode::decode_utf8($value) to get perl to treat it as unicode, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: You have something against CGI->param()?

Answer (score 4):

That [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI) style could be improved while fixing your encoding decoding issue. Try this–

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
use CGI ":standard";
use HTML::Entities;

print
    header("text/html; charset=utf-8"),
    start_html("Thank you!"),
    h1("Thank You!"),
    h3("Your feedback is greatly appreciated.");

if ( my $feedback = decode_utf8( param("feedback") ) )
{
    print
        p("The user wrote:"),
        blockquote( encode_utf8( encode_entities($feedback) ) );
}

print end_html();
```

Proper encoding and decoding between octets/bytes and utf-8 is necessary to avoid surprises and allow the Perl to behave as you’d expect.

For example, you can drop this in–

```
    h4("Which capitalizes as:"),
    blockquote( encode_utf8( uc $feedback ) );
```

And see character conversions work like so: å™ç∂®r£ ➟ Å™Ç∂®R£

Update: added `encode_entities`. NEVER print user input back without escaping the HTML. Update to update: which actually will end up escaping the utf-8 depending on the setup (you can have it only escape ['"<>] for example)…

Comment: Ashley, you're amazing!  For anyone who is looking at this question, the code worked as is.  One note however, on the html page, make sure and add "accept-charset="UTF-8"" to the form tag.  So it should look like this:
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="test.cgi" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Comment: Another question:
In this line "blockquote( encode_utf8( encode_entities($feedback) ) );", what is the purpose of "encode_utf8( encode_entities("?  
I removed that part of the print statement and it still worked just fine.

Comment: @chaojishuai: :) the encode_entities is actually turning everything into ASCII so at that point there’s no need to deal with the encoding out. You might not want to do that for a few reasons, including the size of the output; &hellip; is more bytes than … for example. Here’s how to neuter the HTML while still sending utf-8:         `encode_utf8( encode_entities($feedback,q{&'"><}) )`. The accept-charset is a good addition. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Perl are you using?  This works for me with v5.10.1 on i686-cygwin-thread-multi-64int:

```
perl -E 'use utf8; use encoding("utf8"); $_="中文"; say; s/(\w)/$1 /g; say'
```

Output:

> 中文
>   中 文

I'm sure you've read [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source for the thank you page, the content is:

```
&#20013;&#25991;<br>
&# 2 0 0 1 3;&# 2 5 9 9 1;
```

So it seems like `$FORM{'feedback'}` is arriving as HTML entities rather than as UTF-8. You probably need to convert those entities to real UTF-8 characters before working on the data, I'm not sure the best way to do that.